# Convert string to date python strptime error

Tags: python-3.x, strptime

I tried to convert this date string: Wed May 23 15:45:43 +0000 2018 to a python date object with strptime.
I checked how I'm supposed to use it but I definitely don't understand where my problem is.

I just tried this

```
date = datetime.strptime('Wed May 23 15:45:43 +0000 2018', '%a %b %d %x %z %Y')
```

It suppose to be in the right format but I got this error:

```
sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'd' as group 5; was group 3 at position 169
```

Does it mean that 23 isn't a %d format ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format doesn't match the date string. To know more about the format refer to this https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html.
I have made the correct format for your code. Here is the working code

```
from datetime import datetime
date = datetime.strptime('Wed May 23 15:45:43 +0000 2018',
                         '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y')
print(date) # Output 2018-05-23 15:45:43+00:00
```

Working code is here https://ideone.com/ONDSyD

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. in that case what is the usage of %X ?